# A new process based on a markov chains and a gaussian process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, gaussian

I have a hard time trying to solve this exercise :

> Suppose that we have the CTMC $X(t)$ at the stationnary state such that
> $$ Q_X = \begin{bmatrix}
> -\lambda & \lambda \\ 
> \lambda & -\lambda
> \end{bmatrix}
>  $$
> We build the process $Y(t)$ like that
> $$Y(t) = \begin{cases}
> 0 &\text{ if } \;  X(t) = 0 \\
> A &\text{ if } \;  X(t) = 1
> \end{cases}
> $$
> where $A \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
>
> a) Find the density functionf of $Y$ : $f_{Y(t)}(y)$ for all $y \in\mathbb{R}$.
>
> b) Find the $\mathbb{E}[Y(t)]$.
>
> c) Find the aucorrelation function of $Y$ : $R_Y(\tau)$.

I think that b) could be solve with the density of $Y$ but how can we deduce the density of $Y$ ? Does anyone have a hint ?

Also I don't see how to solve c) even with the density. In fact the problem is really confusing for me, I'm not sure that I understand the problem well : if $X$ at time $t$ is at state $0$ then $Y$ takes value $0$, but if $X$ at time $t$ is at state $1$ then $Y$ is  distributed with a normal distribution ?

Any help is welcome, thanks !